# OnBlur Issue in JQuery Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I have a DatimePicker written in jQuery, which consists of a input text and a button. On clicking the button, the calendar will be launched/shown.
Now , the issue is that I have server-side onChange event on the input text.
 When I put the cursor on the textbox and click the button to launch the calendar, instead of launching the calendar directly, server-side postback occurs. 
I don't want this behavior and don't know how to solve it.
It means, if focus is moved from the input to the button, I do NOT want onBlur to occur.
How can I solve this??

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the postback from happening by returning false in your jQuery event function attached to the button.

Comment: My question is to occur postback on every other situations except clicking the button beside the textbox

Answer (score 1):

### i think you are using asp:button,in which runat is set to server.if then that is the reason of the post back.replace asp:button with <

input type="button" onclick="your java script function"/>

Comment: My question is to occur postback on every other situations except clicking the button beside the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post some code to get a more specific answer.

If you are using an `<asp:TextBox />`, make sure that AutoPostBack is set to false (this should be the default).

If your jquery datepicker uses a click on a button to trigger the popup it should be ensuring no default behviour of the button occurs. You definatley shouldn't use an `<asp:Button />` server control to avoid asp.net Postback interference. Use an `<input type='button' />` or image.

Comment: My question is to occur postback on every other situations except clicking the button beside the textbox